# How to iterate a multidimensional dict in a pre-specified order in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a nested dictionary (because I want to access it by key) `agenda`, but I need to access the values in a specified order, for `k` I'm using a list, and `k2` are date strings in iso format. I've red that I must access the nested dict structure like this:

```
{% for k, a_dict in agenda.items %}
  {{ k }}
  {% for k2, v in a_dict.items %}
    {{ k }}-{{ k2 }}-{{ v.attribute }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But then I cannot seem to find a way to specify the order of the iteration. Is there any other two dimensional data structure accessible from a django template in a pre-specified order? Am I missing something obvious?

Thnx in advance,

pablete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python dict not maintain order. You must use a data structure which mantains the order, Example: SortedDict

```
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict
```

Comment: If so, wouldn't it be better to use the "normal" python [ordered dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: Sure! I forgot that python also had an implementation of OrderedDict